# Delay a Transition to a page while still keeping audio on button

Tags: html

I have a button on a page, that should lead to another page but also play a sound when getting clicked. I do manage to code both functions separately but struggle to have them work at the same time. The sound is 4sec long so I thought of adding a delay for the transition to the next page through setTimeout. But it doesn't work.

```
<body>
    <h3 class="text">The haunting of</h3>
    <h1 class="text">Ypsilon 14</h1>
    <div>
      <div>
        <audio
          src="audio/mixkit-horror-deep-drum-heartbeat-559.wav"
          autostart="false"
        ></audio>
        <button onclick="clickCreCharSound(), clickCreCharTrans();">
          Create Character
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
            function clickCreCharSound() {
              let sound = document.querySelector("audio");
              sound.play();
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
              clickCreCharTrans() {
              window.location.href = "createChar.html";
            }
      },4000)
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is wrap both of the calls into it's one function.
Also I think you should look into what the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function does.

The way you had it setup was that the script executes it will call the timeout, as soon as you open the document. But since you have a function call in there, it behaves differently (weirdly).

```
      <button onclick="playAndRedirect()">Create Character</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function clickCreCharSound() {
      let sound = document.querySelector('audio');
      sound.play();
    }

    const playAndRedirect = () => {
      clickCreCharSound();
      setTimeout(() => {
          window.location.href = 'createChar.html';
      }, 4000);
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that actually helped. I tried something similar before but didn't think about calling the function within the second variable.

Comment: @A_Sar
if it solved your problem, you can mark it as an answer and upvote it.
Your welcome.